# What will be best practice for bean creation fallback?

Tags: java, spring

I have 3 beans which implements same interface. But i want to instantiate only one of them, if A is available then A, if there is no A then B, and if there is no A and B then C.
When i had only two of them it was simple, default one had '@ConditionalOnMissingBean' annotation. But not sure will that work with 3 of them. 
Is it possible to solve this with annotations?
I don't want to create factory method, as I have multiple applications using those components, and i dont have ability to change some of them

Comment: Are the beans in different modules? Can you show a java example with two beans?

Comment: @MarkBramnik each bean lives in different module, and i have 3 types of applications. One which has all 3 beans , one with B and C  and last type which has only C. Scenarios 2 and 3 can be covered by putting annotation `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` on class/factory  but not sure how to solve issue with 3 beans

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using the `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` [annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingBean.html) , you should set the code like this:

```
@Configuration
public class ConditionalOnMissingBeanConfig {

    @Bean
    public A beanA(){
        return new A(); // will initialize as normal
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name="beanA")
    public B beanB(){
        return new B(); // it will not initialize as 
                        // beanA is present in the beanFactory.
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name="beanB")
    public C beanC(){
        return new C(); // will get initialized as there is no 
                        // bean with name beanB in BeanFactory.
    }

}
```

Conditional that only matches when the specified bean is missing from the beanfactory. This will only match when the bean definition is processed by the application context and as such is recommended to be used by auto-configuration classes only.

Comment: it's nice solution, but not sure is that what i'm looking for, as module with bean C does not know about A and B

Comment: Thanks... and if you use 3 variables as indicator shared among the modules?

Answer (score 0):

Let me propose an alternative approach:

You can introduce a configuration variable that will denote the "domain" related explanation of what should the system do

Example:

If A, B, C are, say, different caching strategies (in-memory, redis, ehcache), then introduce the following configuration value:

```
caching.type=ehcache // or in-memory or redis
```

Then the beans can be declared as follows:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(name="caching.type" , havingValue="in-memory", matchIfMissing = true) // this is a fallback if no property is specified
class InMemoryCaching implements CachingStrategy {}

@ConditionalOnProperty(name="caching.type" , havingValue="ehcache", matchIfMissing = false) 
class EhcacheCaching implements CachingStrategy {}

@ConditionalOnProperty(name="caching.type" , havingValue="redis", matchIfMissing = false) 
class RedisCaching implements CachingStrategy {}
```

I know its slightly different solution, but it has the following benefits:

- its easy to add yet another implementation of  the interface - no code changes in existing beans
- beans are not aware of each other even not at the level of bean names in spring
- easy to debug - just look at the configuration property value
- this approach can be applied to `@Configuration` and manage set of beans